# fetch all data having a Price BETWEEN 100000 AND 10000000

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a table named `articles` with a column named `price`.

When a user on my web app selects both `Price Min` and `Price Max`, I need to perform a query like this:

```
$priceMin = 100000;
$priceMax = 10000000;

$query = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE price BETWEEN $priceMin AND $priceMax';
```

However, when the selected `Price Min is <= 100000` and `Price Max is >= 10000000` (10 Million), I don't have any output with a `Price` greater than `900000` even though rows with values above `900000` do exist.

The table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE articles ( 
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 name varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 price varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 source varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: You'll want to do a convert on the table which will be bad because you won't be able to use that column for indexes. When you convert though, you may run into a conversion problem so be aware of that. You may need to do some try catch error handling when converting. (Comma's in numbers, spaces, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Storing numeric data in a varchar column is causing your difficulty.

You can see this effect with a very simple test.

First a table with two columns where we'll store identical data; one column is a varchar, the other is an integer.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    v varchar(100) NOT NULL
    , n int NOT NULL
);
```

Insert some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO test (v, n)
VALUES (0, '0')
    , (1, '1')
    , (2, '2')
    , (100, '100')
    , (99, '99');
```

Show the data, ordered by the varchar column:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY v;
```

Results:

```
╔═════╦═════╗
║  v  ║  n  ║
╠═════╬═════╣
║   0 ║   0 ║
║   1 ║   1 ║
║ 100 ║ 100 ║
║   2 ║   2 ║
║  99 ║  99 ║
╚═════╩═════╝
```

Show the data, ordered by the integer column:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY n;
```

```
╔═════╦═════╗
║  v  ║  n  ║
╠═════╬═════╣
║   0 ║   0 ║
║   1 ║   1 ║
║   2 ║   2 ║
║  99 ║  99 ║
║ 100 ║ 100 ║
╚═════╩═════╝
```

The varchar column is sorted alphabetically, whereas the integer column is sorted numerically.

You should consider altering the `price` column to a numeric data type that supports the precision and magnitude you require.  Refer to the MySQL developer guide for [fixed-point data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) for more details.  I'd suggest considering `decimal(18, 4)` as a starting point for prices.  18 digits is the precision, i.e. the total number of digits that can be stored.  4 is the scale, which is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.  If the `price` column was defined as `decimal(18, 4)`, it would be able to store values such as 99999999999999.9999, and allow them to be sorted correctly.  Defining the column as a varchar is problematic since it will allow you to store `hedgehog` as well as `10000`, which will lead to a variety of problems, not least of which will be the inability to obtain a total price of articles in a group.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree with Max Vernon in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207759/39384) that the basic problem is your design storing prices in text columns, you could get away with this query by converting your values to numeric before comparing them.

This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9e9e015fe0bffeb364fbe2fd4eb8bf4) shows the effects of converting to numeric before sorting/comparing.

Do however keep in mind that your design will keep getting you into problems, as you will always have to convert the string to a number when comparing them or perform calculus on them (addition might result in concatenation), so the best solution is, as Max advised, to use the correct data type.